# How to set all items of a List Object with Public Variable to the same value at once?

Tags: c#

I have a List of a Class (.cs file) that I created, and I just want to set all of the public variables in this class to the same value of false or true, depending on another variable.

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to loop through each object in the `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do this...in your class, make a method to set the values of whatever you want:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public bool Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2 { get; set; } 
    public bool Prop3 { get; set; } 
    public bool Prop4 { get; set; }

    public void SetAllProps(bool theValue)
    {
        Prop1 = theValue;
        Prop2 = theValue;
        Prop3 = theValue;
        Prop4 = theValue;
    }
}
```

And then with a `List` like this:

```
List<SomeClass> listOfClasses = new List<SomeClass>();
```

You could set all the values like:

```
listOfClasses.ForEach(x => x.SetAllProps(true));
```

Comment: Cheers, didn't think of this, thought it would be easier to do this using `Linq` or something similar without the need for another method.  Thanks for the input and for the example!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public method inside the class which updates each variable with the same value. and you can just call the method for each item in the list.

And to update all local variables in the method you can just use something simple like

`var1 = var2 = var3 = var4 = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Reflection`

```
var list = new List<object>() { new TestDataClass(), new TestDataClass() };
foreach (var instance in list) 
    SetObjectProperties(instance, true);
```

---

```
public class TestDataClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; } // Only set this property
    public DateTime C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get { return false; } }
    private bool E { get; set; }
}

public void SetObjectProperties<T>(object target, T value)
{
    var propInfos = target.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var propInfo in propInfos.Where(i => i.PropertyType == typeof(T) && i.GetSetMethod() != null))
    {
        propInfo.SetValue(target, value, null);
    }
}
```